# Getting error while scraping data from covers.com using R

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to scrape data from a web site using R. I am newbie at scraping data.

My code is as below:

```
library(XML)
url1<-"http://www.covers.com/sports/NCAAB/matchups?selectedDate=2015-02-28"
data1<-htmlTreeParse(url1)
getNodeSet(data1,"//div[@class = 'data-competition-type']")
```

However, I et such an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "XMLDocumentContent"
```

Why do I get this eror? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Basically, switch to `htmlParse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getNodeSet` has a `doc` argument that, as per the help page (see [`?getNodeSet`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xml/docs/matchNamespaces)), should be " 
an object of class XMLInternalDocument."

You are getting that error because your `data1` object is not an object of class "XMLInternalDocument"; it's an object of class "XMLDocumentContent"